# How can I show text in the ActionBar in my apps Preference screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, sharedpreferences

I am using an Activity and Fragment as a Preferences screen in my app, as per [Google's recommended format](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html). I am wondering how I can get the action bar in this activity to say "Settings". Also, how can I include a back arrow to return to the calling activity? Is this a built-in function in Android, or would I need some extra drawable resource for the arrow?

Currently, with the following code I am getting the error `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Here is my preferences Activity and Fragment:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        //setupActionBar();

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:title="@string/settings_title"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="settings_game_mode"
        android:title="@string/settings_game_mode">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="game_mode_list"
            android:title="Select Rule Mode"
            android:summary="%s"
            android:entries="@array/game_mode_list_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/game_mode_list_entries_values"
            android:defaultValue="FIRST_TO_21" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And this is the style that my SettingsActivity is using:

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of errors with your setup:

- if you are using `Toolbar` to set up your own appbar, you need to use `NoActionBar` variant of the theme
- `Toolbar` cannot be part of your `preferences.xml` as that's strictly for the preferences
- `PreferenceScreen` has no `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes as it is *not* a layout element

The main problem is that you are replacing `android.R.id.content` with the preferences fragment. This means that you cannot use custom layout elements so this leaves you with two options:

#### Option 1 - Normal layout

Use a normal layout that you set with `setContentView(...)`. This layout should contain the `Toolbar` and a container (e.g. a `FrameLayout`) for the fragment, then you "replace" that container with the prefs fragment. The `Toolbar` can be set to be the action bar by calling [`setSupportActionBar(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)). Note that you must use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as your theme's parent in this case.

#### Option 2 - Replacing `android.R.id.content`

If you want to stick with the base content container replacement method, you'll need to keep using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as your theme's parent, then use the usual methods to control the toolbar:

- set the `label` attribute in the manifest for `SettingsActivity` (or if you want to set it programmatically, call [`setTitle(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(int)) in your `onCreate(...)`)
- get the `ActionBar` by calling [`getSupportActionBar()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar())

  - you can call [`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) on the returned instance to enable the back arrow

The back arrow click can be handled in your Activity's `onOptionsItemSelected(...)`, for example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> Note that this should be handled manually only if you don't have a parent activity set up in the manifest. Check the [Adding an Up Action](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action.html) guide for more details.

---

As a last point, let me introduce you to my [support preferences v7 fix lib](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) that solves a lot of problem you might face using the official lib. The [v26-beta](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix/tree/v26-beta) branch contains a nice README (the master is a bit of a mess now) but both the *master* (based on 25.4.0) and the *v26-beta* (based on 26.0.0-beta2) have sample apps (the "app" folder) that should be easy to copy / follow to create your own settings screen. The sample app shows you *option 1*.

Comment: Thanks so much. I went with option 2. One issue I am having is when I set up the `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` in my manifest for the SettingsActivity it takes me to an entirely new instance of MainActivity and not the old one, is there a way to get around this? I did take a look at your library, but for this app I am not going to be using many 3rd party libraries for now.

Comment: The [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp) guide shows how to handle this behavior. The easiest is probably to set the launch mode to "singleTop" on your parent `Activity` by setting the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` attribute in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation here for adding the toolbar: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Then call the horribly named [setDisplayShowHomeEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)) and [setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) on the action bar to get it show the back button.

Your standard Activity.setTitle("Settings") will show the string "Settings" in the toolbar.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I think that got me closer, but now I'm getting a new error. I updated my code and included the error in my original post.

Comment: Your toolbar should be declared in the Activity's layout file and then you should get it and set it as the toolbar in the Activity onCreate, not the Fragment. Follow the instructions at the developer site I linked.